Returning the error "NX_SECURE_TLS_ISSUER_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND" when connecting to https on netxduo
Testing https with netxduo on nucleo-h563zi board. However, I keep returning the error "NX_SECURE_TLS_ISSUER_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND".
I checked http communication normally for Google access. Then I registered the CA I downloaded from Google. Below is what I checked in debugging.
enter image description here
When checking variables in the _nx_secure_x509_distinguished_name_field_compare() function call, I was able to see that the data received from remote_buffer was different in name from trusted_certificate.
Trusted_certificate is the CA I downloaded from Google. Can you tell me the difference?
